# How to use hidden parameters in jsp

Tags: jquery, jsp

While i click employee name it will open new tab and this employee code has fetched in the value of textbox. That new page has filter process so only need that employee code has value of textbox.

```
 function view_emp(ecode){
       window.open('SomeServlet?operation=view&&empcode='+ecode ,'_blank');
 }
```

In that servlet i will redirect new jsp page, and fetch value in textbax. Here that parameters has displayed in the url. How can i pass these value has hidden.

Comment: let me get this ,do u want to pass a paramter from one jsp page to another jsp via a servlet?

Comment: Explain, that what you are trying to achieve with this code? Your title and question does't tell that what are you trying to do.

Comment: i am saying pass values as hidden method from jsp to servlet.. and redirect jsp file form servlet in new tab.. help me how to so that..

Answer (score 0):

The parameter is displayed in url because  you are sending GET request to the server, instead change the request method type to POST and submit, it won't be visible in url now, but you need to some minor changes in servlet/controller code.